# how can I integrate WhatsApp into my ios app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I want to develop an iphone app ,in which user can send a common message (Broadcast Message) to unlimited (Select All Contacts) and send to all at one time (In single attempt ) .It's possible to share images or text you want through Whatsapp in a iOS app?

Any idea regarding this?

Answer (score 2):

There's also a WhatsAppKit on Github now: [Check Link](http://github.com/fawkeswei/WhatsAppKit)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you can use Whats app into App up till now. If so than also i will suggest not to rely on that.

If you want to make an feature for to broadcast a text message or image the best way is to implement your own. You can do the following:

- Use xmpp Protocol
- Implement push notification to notify for new broadcast messages
- Create API for sending/receiving text messages & image & call it when you get notification

For more guidance refer this : http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-chat_users-ios